# Check for compatibility

Tags: cmake, gnu, aix

I have an application that requires openssl which is compiled using cmake. The stable AIX 7.1 cmake version is 3.14.3

In the cmake build file I have a the following test

```
include(CheckCSourceCompiles)
check_c_source_compiles(check_openssl.c HAS_NEW_ENOUGH_OPENSSL)
```

check_openssl.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "/usr/local/include/openssl/ossl_type.h"
#include "/usr/local/include/openssl/evp.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   printf("out = %d", !EVP_aes_256_ctr);
   return !EVP_aes_256_ctr;
}
```

`gcc` compiles with no problem at all and the comment prints out as expected. However, I get compile error when I test it with cmake.

Update 1:
Having followed @squareskittles answer and did a cmake upgrade to 3.15.0 (built from source in AIX) I am still getting nothing. The only error message I got was `-- Performing Test HAS_NEW_ENOUGH_OPENSSL - Failed`

As for the command I am using for the build

```
cmake -DJVM_ARCH_DATA_MODEL=64 -DUSE64bit=true -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

Comment: Do you get any error-message, or simply _doesn't work?_ (Note: Is it actually an AIX3? Then your hardware is 20+ years old now, isn't it?)

Comment: My mistake for not being clearer. As for the error message I'm not getting any out

Comment: Ok. Exactly what command did you try, and what result did you get? Nothing at all happened?

Comment: "I get compile error when I test it with cmake." - show that error (add it to the question post).

Comment: @CandyHo Your C code needs to be placed *inline* in your CMake file, within quotes. See my expanded answer.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** The correct use of `check_c_source_compiles()` requires inserting the actual C code *inline* within your CMake file. In addition, because your code contains quotes, you must escape the quotes with backslashes (`\"`). See my example below.

---

This [`check_c_source_compiles()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCSourceCompiles.html) command should be used to check **if** a source can be compiled and linked to an executable. If it can, then you should use `add_executable()` or `add_library()` to actually compile it. Once compiled, then you can run it to print the comment message. Or, if you want to check compile, link, and run compatibility all in one sweep, you should use [`check_c_source_runs()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCSourceRuns.html) instead, as @Tsyvarev suggested. You haven't posted a complete example of your code, but I would imagine you could do something like this:

```
# Check for compile, link, run compatibility.
include(CheckCSourceRuns)
check_c_source_runs(
    "
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include \"/usr/local/include/openssl/ossl_type.h\"
    #include \"/usr/local/include/openssl/evp.h\"

    int main(int argc, char **argv){
        printf(\"out = %d\", !EVP_aes_256_ctr);
        return !EVP_aes_256_ctr;
    } 
    "
    HAS_NEW_ENOUGH_OPENSSL
)

# Build if it is compatible.
if(HAS_NEW_ENOUGH_OPENSSL)
  add_executable(MyOpenSslTest check_openssl.c)
endif()

...

unset(HAS_NEW_ENOUGH_OPENSSL CACHE)
```

**NOTE:** These commands rely on other variables to retrieve all the necessary compile/link options to successfully test compatibility. You'll likely need to set `CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES`, `CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES`, or some of the other variables listed in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCSourceRuns.html) to run the `check_c_*` commands without errors. You can inspect the `CMakeError.log` file to see what errors may be occurring during the compatibility check.

Also, The result variable `HAS_NEW_ENOUGH_OPENSSL` will get cached, and won't change if the source file changes, so you might want to `unset` it after you are done using it.